# How do I avoid inadvertently switching workspaces?

Tags: mission-control, macos, spaces

I keep accidentally dragging windows into other workspaces on my Macbook Air running OS X Lion.

Can I disable dragging into other workspaces or make doing so more difficult?

Answer (score 5):

There's a hidden preference for adjusting the delay in seconds:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock workspaces-edge-delay -float 0.5
osascript -e 'quit app "Dock"'
```

It can be set to an arbitrarily high value to disable dragging windows to other spaces.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, this still works, even on High Sierra.

Answer (score 2):

TinkerTool has this option in the Applications tab, Mission Control, Delay when dragging window to adjacent space: Default / Short / No Delay.
No Delay was selected on my computer, but I don't remember if I chose that at some point. I looked into this because I wanted the "windows aero snap" feature, I just found and installed [Cinch by Irradiated Software](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/cinch/). The Spaces "swipe" would happen before Cinch was able to do its thing.

Answer (score 0):

With the [Warp pref-pane](http://www.ksuther.com/warp/), you can set a delay and/or require a modifier key(s) to allow a space change.